# Issue with Bootstrap grid system and vertical aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Issue**

I finally found an easy way of vertical aligning `div` elements and any other type of element, using the CSS properties/values `display:flex; align-items: center`. Only issue now is that the Boostrap grid system i.e. `col-*-12` doesn't work. If I set a div to expand 12 columns when on a small screen, it doesn't react, in less I remove the styling used for vertically aligning the items.

**Aim**

To be able to use the grid system and vertically align elements. Any idea why `display: flex` is preventing the grid from working?

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-container padding-top--sm padding-bottom--sm">
    <div class="row" style="display:flex;align-items:center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <img src="#" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-md-center">
            <p class="txt--white no-margin-bottom h-thin"> Lorem Ipsume, lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-md-right">
            <span class="txt--white">support@support.com</span><br>
            <span class="no-margin-bottom txt--white">001111111111 (8am - 8pm GMT)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.padding-top--sm { padding-top: 1rem; }
.padding-bottom--sm { padding-bottom: 1rem; }


.header-container { 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;    
width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot, added it now

Comment: This might interest you: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are not letting your row "wrap" its contents.

By default its is set to `nowrap` value which means it does not allow the content to extend the container.

Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` property to your row style

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex;align-items:center;flex-wrap: wrap;">
...
</div>
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/GjZdPA)

> PS: Consider **avoiding inline styles**, use **external** or atleast **internal styles** as much as possible

Comment: You absolute beast! Thank you. I am guessing `display: flex`, prevents it from doing so in less stated?

Comment: Cheers buddy .. I didn't understand what you meant by - less stated ?

Comment: In less I add `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: By less do you mean in "smaller device width" or file extension ".less" ??

Comment: It's OK, it's just me asking something irrelevant. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It actually depends on your requirement. If you use `flex-wrap: wrap` only on smaller width then on desktop the contents will not go to next row. If you are ok with this then use it only on smaller device width media query :-) Hope this helped